# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attachments.wsgi'

Tags: python, django, deployment, render

i am trying to deploy my django app on render but i am finding this error
attachments is my projectname
my code for wsgi is
"""
WSGI config for attachments project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named `application`.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'attachments.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctld4.png)

i was expecting a sucess message